# Linq - Select single item from child collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a parent child collection objects and was wondering how to get a single item from the child collection using Linq

Parent Collection

```
Public Class FaultCodeModel

    Public Property ID As Short
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property FaultCodeDetails As List(Of FaultCodeDetailModel)

End Class
```

Child Collection

```
Public Class FaultCodeDetailModel

    Public Property ID As Short
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property NotifyPurchasing As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyPurchasingAfterHits As Short
    Public Property NotifyExpediting As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyExpeditingAfterHits As Short
    Public Property NotifyBuyer As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyBuyerAfterHits As Short
    Public Property NotifySupplier As Boolean
    Public Property NotifySupplierAfterHits As Short
    Public Property NotiifyProPack As Boolean
    Public Property NotiifyProPackAfterHits As Short
    Public Property NotifyGoodsInTeamLeader As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyGoodsInTeamLeaderAfterHits As Short

End Class
```

I have tried the below Linq query but it is returning multiple child items where the parent ID field is matched.

```
Dim var = From fcd In FaultCodes Where fcd.FaultCodeDetails.Any(Function(w) w.ID.Equals(faultCodeDetailID))
            Select fcd.FaultCodeDetails
```

How do I get a single item from the child collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim fcdID = 4711
Dim fcdm = (From fc In FaultCodes
           From fcd In fc.FaultCodeDetails
           Where fcd.ID = fcdID
        Select fcd).FirstOrDefault
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Comment: Think this is missing the closing bracket from the Any. where does it go?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to have this:

```
FaultCodes.SelectMany(Function(w) w.FaultCodeDetails)
          .Where(Function(w) w.ID.Equals(faultCodeDetailID))
```

This returns all the child items whose `ID` equals `faultCodeDetailID`.

(I am a C# guy, maybe the VB.NET syntax is a bit off. Please correct it yourself)

---

C# version:

```
FaultCodes.SelectMany(x => x.FaultCodeDetails)
          .Where(x => x.ID == faultCodeDetailID)
```

Comment: @PhilMurray: Added C# version and fixed VB.NET version.

Comment: That also works, thanks. Here is the correct Vb Dim var = FaultCodes.SelectMany(Function(x) x.FaultCodeDetails).Where(Function(x2) x2.ID.Equals(faultCodeDetailID))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Dim Obj = (yourcollection).Where(Function(c) c.FieldName.ToString() = "YourValue").FirstOrDefault()
```